# What is the best way to deserialize Azure Search result to your own model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, deserialization, azure-cognitive-search

Currently what I'm doing is serializing the `JsonResult.Data` then Deserialized into `dynamic` variable before looping in each row and get the `Document`. Is there any way to handle this? Thanks

```
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm_))
                searchTerm_ = "*";
            _azureSearch = new AzureSearchService("afindexdev");
            JsonResult result = new JsonResult
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = _azureSearch.SearchAssetFactory(searchTerm_).Results
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Data);
            var resultJsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

            foreach (dynamic row in resultJsonString)
            {
                var associatemItem = new AssociatedItem();
                associatemItem.Id = row.Document.Id;
                associatemItem.Title = row.Document.Title;
                associatemItem.Type = row.Document.Type;

                searcResult.AssociatedItems.Add(associatemItem);
            }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question a bit? It isn't clear if you're asking about a 3rd party Azure Search client, or about a general scenario.

I don't recognize the code you're using to call Azure Search. Have you tried the official .NET SDK? http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search

Comment: @BruceJohnston: I'm calling Azure search inside 'AzureSearchService' but that's not my question. I already have the data from azure and stored in inside 'result' variable, my question is what is the best way to deserialized the result in this scenario.

Comment: Why do you need to deserialize the results from .NET code? Aren't they already deserialized when you get them back from SearchAssetFactory? Normally when I've seen code like this that creates a JsonResult, it's for the purposes of sending search results back to a browser. What is your overall scenario?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

var associatedItem = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< List < AssociatedItem > >(json);

That way you don't have to make your object yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your model with properties which you want to deserialize with attribute [SerializePropertyNamesAsCamelCase]. This attribute is included to Microsoft.Azure.Search library. After that, all you need to do is to define your model in search generic - like this Hotel class

```
var sp = new SearchParameters();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
{
    sp.Filter = filter;
}

DocumentSearchResult<Hotel> response = indexClient.Documents.Search<Hotel>(searchText, sp);
```

You can find more info [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-dotnet-sdk/#core-scenarios)